# Cuda not copying large arrays to device

Tags: arrays, cuda, nvcc

I am new to CUDA, so I am sorry if I made any silly mistake, but this seems puzzling to me. The following code works perfectly for arrays of size up to 620 elements. When we change the NV def (number of vortexes) from 621 on, all arrays in the kernel become of NAN. I hope someone can explain this.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define NP 20000
#define DT 0.01 
#define NV 620  // Fails if 621 or larger
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__device__ float d_x0[NV];
__device__ float d_y0[NV];
__global__ static void  calc(float *d_x, float *d_y, float Lx, float Ly ){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    float fx, fy, t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, dx, dy, pi = acos(-1.0);
    int j, n;
    if (i<NV) {
        // For array error detection
        if (isnan(d_x0[i])) printf(" dx(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_y0[i])) printf(" dy(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_x[i])) printf(" x(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_y[i])) printf(" y(%d)!",i);
        fx = 0.0;   fy = 0.0;
        for (j = 0 ; j < NV ; j++){ 
            dx = d_x0[i] - d_x0[j];
            dy = d_y0[i] - d_y0[j];
            t0 = 2.0 * dy / Ly;
            t1 = sin(2.0 * pi * dx / Lx);
            t3 = cos(2.0 * pi * dx / Lx);
                for (n = -10 ; n <= 10 ; n++){
                    if (n == 0){
                        if (j != i){
                            t2 = cosh(2.0 * pi * Ly / Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                            t4 = sinh(2.0 * pi * Ly/Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                            fx = fx + t1 / (t2 - t3);
                            fy = fy + t4 / (t2 - t3);
                        }
                    }   
                    else{
                        t2 = cosh(2.0 * pi * Ly / Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                        t4 = sinh(2.0 * pi * Ly/Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                        fx = fx + t1 / (t2 - t3);
                        fy = fy + t4 / (t2 - t3);                           
                    }
                }
                fy = fy - t0;
        }
        fx = fx * pi / Lx;
        fy = fy * pi / Lx;
        d_x[i] = d_x0[i] + fx * DT;
        d_y[i] = d_y0[i] + fy * DT;
        // Clip box
        if(d_x[i] > Lx)   d_x[i] = d_x[i] - (abs(d_x[i] / Lx) * Lx);
        if(d_x[i] < 0.0)  d_x[i] = d_x[i] + ((abs(d_x[i] / Lx) + 1.0) * Lx);
        if(d_y[i] > Ly)   d_y[i] = d_y[i] - (abs(d_y[i] / Ly) * Ly);
        if(d_y[i] < 0.0)  d_y[i] = d_y[i] + ((abs(d_y[i] / Ly) + 1.0) * Ly);
    }
}
__global__ static void  update(float *d_x, float *d_y ){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i<NV) {
        d_x0[i] = d_x[i];
        d_y0[i] = d_y[i];
    }
}
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    float Lx, Ly, dv;
    int i, k;
    int size = (NV) * sizeof(float);
    float* x = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* y = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* x0 = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* y0 = (float*)malloc(size);
    dv = 0.12 * 16.0;
    Lx = sqrt(2.0 / 3.0 * sqrt(3.0) * NV / dv); 
    Ly = Lx * sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
    for(i=0 ; i < NV ; i++){
        x0[i] = Lx * (rand() % 1000)/1000;  
        y0[i] = Ly * (rand() % 1000)/1000;
    }
    // GPU mem management
    float *d_x = NULL, *d_y = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 1");
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_y, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 2");
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_x0, x0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbol fail 1");
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_y0, y0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbol fail 2");
    int threadsPerBlock = 512;
    int blocksPerGrid = (NV + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    for(k = 0; k < NP ; k++){
        calc<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>( d_x, d_y, Lx, Ly);
        cudaCheckErrors("kernel 1 call fail");
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        update<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>( d_x, d_y);
        cudaCheckErrors("kernel 2 call fail");
        if (k%((NP)/200)==0) {
            cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemCopy fail 1");
            cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemCopy fail 2");
            printf("(%d%%) ",100*k/NP);
            for(i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) printf(",%5.2f,%5.2f ", x[i], y[i]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 1");
    cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 2");
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(x0, d_x0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyFromSymbol fail 1");
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(y0, d_y0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyFromSymbol fail 2");
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
    return 0;
}
```

I tried changing block and grid structures, compiling with `-arch=sm_35 -arch=sm_30` and `--cudart=shared` options and even change the arrays from **float** to **double**, nothing has worked.

Answer (score 1):

Your code never initializes `d_x` or `d_y` arrays.

You allocate space for them on the device:

```
float *d_x = NULL, *d_y = NULL;
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x, size);
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 1");
cudaMalloc((void**)&d_y, size);
cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 2");
```

But you never initialize them or copy anything to them. That means they have garbage in thme.  So when you call your `calc` kernel, the first lines:

```
    if (isnan(d_x[i])) printf(" x(%d)!",i);
    if (isnan(d_y[i])) printf(" y(%d)!",i);
```

always print out for me.

Fixing that, some of your individual calculations are blowing up at each iteration of your main loop, including the very first `calc` kernel call.  As soon as a single iteration produces a single `d_x` value of `nan`, I hope you can see that this will spread to all the rest of your values on the very next iteration.

To sort this out, I would suggest instrumenting your code with `printf` further.  I found the following modifications to be useful:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <assert.h>
#define NP 20000
#define DT 0.01
#define NV 621  // Fails if 621 or larger
#define cudaCheckErrors(msg) \
    do { \
        cudaError_t __err = cudaGetLastError(); \
        if (__err != cudaSuccess) { \
            fprintf(stderr, "Fatal error: %s (%s at %s:%d)\n", \
                msg, cudaGetErrorString(__err), \
                __FILE__, __LINE__); \
            fprintf(stderr, "*** FAILED - ABORTING\n"); \
            exit(1); \
        } \
    } while (0)

__device__ float d_x0[NV];
__device__ float d_y0[NV];
__global__ static void  calc(float *d_x, float *d_y, float Lx, float Ly ){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    float fx, fy, t0, t1, t2, t3, t4, dx, dy, pi = acos(-1.0);
    int j, n;
    if (i<NV) {
        // For array error detection
        if (isnan(d_x0[i])) printf(" dx(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_y0[i])) printf(" dy(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_x[i])) printf(" x(%d)!",i);
        if (isnan(d_y[i])) printf(" y(%d)!",i);
        fx = 0.0;   fy = 0.0;
        for (j = 0 ; j < NV ; j++){
            dx = d_x0[i] - d_x0[j];
            dy = d_y0[i] - d_y0[j];
            t0 = 2.0 * dy / Ly;
            t1 = sin(2.0 * pi * dx / Lx);
            t3 = cos(2.0 * pi * dx / Lx);
                for (n = -10 ; n <= 10 ; n++){
                    if (n == 0){
                        if (j != i){
                            t2 = cosh(2.0 * pi * Ly / Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                            t4 = sinh(2.0 * pi * Ly/Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                            fx = fx + t1 / (t2 - t3);
            if(isnan(fx)) {printf("!8 %d, %d, %d, %f, %f, %f\n",i, j, n, fx, t2, t3); return;}
                            fy = fy + t4 / (t2 - t3);
                        }
                    }
                    else{
                        t2 = cosh(2.0 * pi * Ly / Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                        t4 = sinh(2.0 * pi * Ly/Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
                        fx = fx + t1 / (t2 - t3);
                        fy = fy + t4 / (t2 - t3);
                    }
                }
                fy = fy - t0;
        }
        fx = fx * pi / Lx;
        fy = fy * pi / Lx;
        d_x[i] = d_x0[i] + fx * DT;
        d_y[i] = d_y0[i] + fy * DT;
        // Clip box
        if(d_x[i] > Lx)   d_x[i] = d_x[i] - (abs(d_x[i] / Lx) * Lx);
        if(d_x[i] < 0.0)  d_x[i] = d_x[i] + ((abs(d_x[i] / Lx) + 1.0) * Lx);
        if(d_y[i] > Ly)   d_y[i] = d_y[i] - (abs(d_y[i] / Ly) * Ly);
        if(d_y[i] < 0.0)  d_y[i] = d_y[i] + ((abs(d_y[i] / Ly) + 1.0) * Ly);
    }
}
__global__ static void  update(float *d_x, float *d_y ){
    int i = blockDim.x * blockIdx.x + threadIdx.x;
    if (i<NV) {
        if (isnan(d_x[i])) assert(0);
        if (isnan(d_y[i])) assert(0);
        d_x0[i] = d_x[i];
        d_y0[i] = d_y[i];
    }
}
int main(int argc,char **argv) {
    float Lx, Ly, dv;
    int i, k;
    int size = (NV) * sizeof(float);
    float* x = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* y = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* x0 = (float*)malloc(size);
    float* y0 = (float*)malloc(size);
    dv = 0.12 * 16.0;
    Lx = sqrt(2.0 / 3.0 * sqrt(3.0) * NV / dv);
    Ly = Lx * sqrt(3.0) / 2.0;
    printf("Lx = %f, Ly = %f\n", Lx, Ly);
    for(i=0 ; i < NV ; i++){
        x0[i] = Lx * (rand() % 1000)/1000;
        y0[i] = Ly * (rand() % 1000)/1000;
        x[i]  = 1.0f;
        y[i]  = 1.0f;
    }
    printf("x0[0] = %f, y0[0] = %f\n", x0[0], y0[0]);
    // GPU mem management
    float *d_x = NULL, *d_y = NULL;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_x, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 1");
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_y, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMalloc fail 2");
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_x0, x0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbol fail 1");
    cudaMemcpyToSymbol(d_y0, y0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyToSymbol fail 2");
    cudaMemcpy(d_x, x, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 1");
    cudaMemcpy(d_y, y, size, cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 2");
    int threadsPerBlock = 512;
    int blocksPerGrid = (NV + threadsPerBlock - 1) / threadsPerBlock;
    for(k = 0; k < NP ; k++){
        printf("iter %d\n", k);
        calc<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>( d_x, d_y, Lx, Ly);
        cudaCheckErrors("kernel 1 call fail");
        cudaDeviceSynchronize();
        update<<<blocksPerGrid, threadsPerBlock>>>( d_x, d_y);
        cudaCheckErrors("kernel 2 call fail");
        if (k%((NP)/200)==0) {
            cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemCopy fail 1");
            cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
            cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemCopy fail 2");
            printf("(%d%%) ",100*k/NP);
            for(i = 1 ; i <= 5 ; i++) printf(",%5.2f,%5.2f ", x[i], y[i]);
            printf("\n\n");
        }
    }
    cudaMemcpy(x, d_x, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 1");
    cudaMemcpy(y, d_y, size, cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpy fail 2");
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(x0, d_x0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyFromSymbol fail 1");
    cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(y0, d_y0, size);
    cudaCheckErrors("cudaMemcpyFromSymbol fail 2");
    cudaFree(d_x);
    cudaFree(d_y);
    return 0;
}
```

These showed me that for elements 86 and 518, the following calculation was blowing up, because t2 = t3 = 1.0:

```
                            fx = fx + t1 / (t2 - t3);
```

Hopefully you can work backward from there.  What I found is that your randomization scheme is producing many duplicate values for `x0`, `y0`:

```
for(i=0 ; i < NV ; i++){
    x0[i] = Lx * (rand() % 1000)/1000;  
    y0[i] = Ly * (rand() % 1000)/1000;
}
```

These duplicate values lead to a value of 0 here:

```
        dx = d_x0[i] - d_x0[j];
```

And cos(0) = 1.0 here:

```
        t3 = cos(2.0 * pi * dx / Lx);
```

And for a few values of `i`, `j`, you are getting a 1 here also:

```
                        t2 = cosh(2.0 * pi * Ly / Lx * (dy / Ly + n));
```

Which leads to t2-t3 = 0, and things blow up.

I don't think any of this is CUDA specific.  I believe this code should blow up in ordinary host code using nested loops as well.  I believe increasing `NV` exacerbates the issue because you have more duplicates in `d_x0`, `d_y0`.

Comment: The reason  `d_x` and `d_y` are not not initialized is because data is created on the device in function `calc`. Data is then copied back to host. Notice the lines `d_x[i] = d_x0[i] + fx * DT;` and `d_y[i] = d_y0[i] + fy * DT;`. Thank you.

Comment: Sure, but notice that the first lines in your `calc` kernel are checking `d_x` and `d_y` for validity, before any of those lines you mention get executed.  Therefore they may be `nan` initially, and those printouts may trigger.  That issue is not the key problem in your code.

Comment: Despite these comments, both codes (original and revised) work fine only for arrays of size under 621 elements. Your code did not present any change on the original issue. I have a GTX Titan with CUDA 6.5.

Comment: If you want to edit your question and post the revised code that you're currently running, I'll take another look.  Alternatively, as a simple test, you may want to put a printf or other indicator in your kernel if it detects that t2-t3 = 0 (before computing the division).

Comment: No significant changes have been made to the posted code. This algorithm is well known in physics and has been extensively used. Point is, if the division in question was determinant for all the elements in the array to become NaNs, it would also happen for array sizes under 621 elements, it doesn't. The problem boundary is exactly 621 elements, what possibly indicates some CUDA/memory/hardware limitation related issue.

Comment: I'm guessing you're on windows.  On linux, I observe a similar behavior breakpoint above 518 elements.  It works below 621 elements (in your case) because your random number generation scheme generates no critical duplicates when the total number of generated numbers is less than what is required for 621 elements.  Once you have critical duplicates, you have the mathematical explosion I describe.  I have advanced considerable logic to show and suggest that this is a math/RNG issue. You have advanced no logic I can see to show why this might be a "CUDA/memory/hardware limitation related issue".

Comment: As a further proof-point of my argument, change your random generation code lines from this: `x0[i] = Lx * (rand() % 1000)/1000;` to this: `x0[i] = Lx * rand()/(float)RAND_MAX;` and similarly for `y0[i]` and I think you'll see the behavior breakpoint move (to some `NV` value higher than 620/621).

Comment: You are right about it not being a GPU specific problem. Just tested the sequential CPU version to find the same anomaly. It is odd though that the boundary is such a crisp value when we're dealing with a random factor.

Comment: The `rand()` RNG generates the exact same random number sequence every time you run your program, unlees you use a different seed, which you're not doing.  So actually the behavior is very predictable and repeatable.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Robert Crovella, the random number generator always generates the same sequence, for which the first repeated coordinate occurs at array position 621 (on windows), what results in the infinite explosion observed. The problem was solved reseeding the generator and adding the following code to the original program to check for superpositions:

```
for(i=1 ; i <= NV ; i++){
    do {
        test=false; 
        x0[i] = Lx * (rand() % 1000)/1000;  
        y0[i] = Ly * (rand() % 1000)/1000;
        x[i]=x0[i]; y[0]=y0[i];
        for(j=1 ; j < i ; j++){
            if (i!=j&&x0[i]==x0[j]&&y0[i]==y0[j]) {
                test=true; 
                printf("(%d)superposto.\n",i);
            }
        }
    } while (test);
    printf("%f, %f\n", x0[i], y0[i]);
}
```